# Fixing this .NET regex

Tags: .net, xml, regex

I'd like to get your kind assistance in finding out what's wrong with a .NET regular expression. I'm over thousands of such expression, but I'm completely stucked at fixing this simple one.

The regex is as follows:

```
(?isx)
            <Field 
                (
                    \s+ 
                    | 
                    name    =   "(?<name>  [^"]*?)" 
                    |
                    type    =   "(?<type>  [^"]*?)"
                    |
                    value   =   "(?<value> [^"]*?)"
                )+
            >‭
                (?<content> .*?)
            </Field>
```

Things I want to catch are XML portions like this ones:

```
<Field name="SolutionList/0/ModuleType" type="Enumeration" value="StartSectionModule"></Field>
<Field name="SolutionList/0/StartSectionModule/Title" type="String">Áttekintés</Field>
<Field name="SolutionList/0/TextModule/HtmlContent" type="RichContent"><![CDATA[]]></Field>
```

And now matter how I try to simplify the expression step by step to try to find the buggy part, I could not manage to achieve any relevant progress in a few hours.

Thanks for your time, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the warnings about parsing html in regex...

There was a small spacing problem.

I took it out of free-spacing mode. This flat regex now works:

```
(?s)<Field(\s+|name="(?<name>[^"]*?)"|type="(?<type>[^"]*?)"|value="(?<value>[^"]*?)")+>(?<content>.*?)</Field>
```

Since you wrote it, I won't explain it to you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a [left-to-right](http://www.charbase.com/202d-unicode-left-to-right-override) invisible character after your first `>`. Remove it and [you'll be fine](http://regex101.com/r/sD9oE0).

Also, you should avoid `(\s+)+`-type situation to avoid catastrophic backtracking:

```
(?isx)
    <Field 
        (?:
            \s+ 
            (?: 
                name    =   "(?<name>  [^"]*?)"
                |
                type    =   "(?<type>  [^"]*?)"
                |
                value   =   "(?<value> [^"]*?)"
            )
        )+
    >
    (?<content> .*?)
    </Field>
```